# jQuery autocomplete label, value in different fields when selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) and have it working but when a user selects an item it then places the value in the text box. I would like it so that when the user selects an item the label is used as the text in the textbox and the value is inserted in a hidden field 'cId'.

I've had a look around and can seem to find a solution.

My values are in a string called ClientCsv like:

```
[ { label: "ClientId1", value: "ClientName1" }, { label: "ClientId2", value: "ClientName2" } ]
```

The jquery I currently use is:

```
$(function () {
var availableTags = [ " & ClientCsv() & " ]; $('#tags').autocomplete({ source: availableTags});
});
```

Form code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tags" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="cId" runat="server" />
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire up the select event for the autocomplete and then prevent the default action of populating the value in the search field.

```
var availableTags = [{ label: "ClientId1", value: "ClientName1" }, { label: "ClientId2", value: "ClientName2"}];

$(function () {
    var txt = $('#tags');
    txt.autocomplete({ 
        source: availableTags,
        select: function(event, ui){
            //put the label in your text field
            txt.val(ui.item.label);

            //put the value in your hidden field
            $('#cId').val(ui.item.value);

            //cancel the event to prevent it populating the value
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @bPratik thanks, I got ahead of myself with ui.item.id (should have been .value).  the edited code above worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, think that works great but one slight issue, if you mouse down over the selections it then puts the ID in the textbox until you click?!

Comment: No problem Stephen, I just duplicated the select: function under focus: and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks again.